# JNA macro function in #define

Tags: java, c, macros, jna

I am trying ported **[spidev.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/spi/spidev.h)** to java using JNA.

How i can port `#define SPI_IOC_RD_MODE_IOR(SPI_IOC_MAGIC, 1, __u8)` from c to java using JNA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "port" a macro definition (here `SPI_IOC_RD_MODE`) to java. JNA may help you to call `_IOR` if this happens to be an exported function of a certain dll.

Comment: How to call _IOR using JNA?